# how to find and replace annotations based on parameters?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, structural-search

I have a big java project using TestNG Test annotation.

I want to add parameter `timeOut=100L` to all tests, that are not part of a group (defined via Test Annotation parameters). We use groups for functional/integration/etc. I want to impact only unit tests, which lack any group.

My unit tests (which are the ones I want to match) have `@Test` annotation by itself, or other parameters. e.g.

```
@Test
public void aSimpleTest() 
{
...

@Test(expectedExceptions = SomeException.class,
        expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = "my error message",
        description = "Test will fail validation on X")
public void aSimpleTestWithAnotatedParameters() {
...

@Test(dataProvider = "testDataProvider")
public void aSimpleTestWithAnotatedParameters(Int InputVal) {
...
```

My first attempt was using IntelliJ Structural Find and Replace:

Search Template:

```
@$Annotation$($param1$ = $value1$,/*...*/ $paramN$ = $valueN$)
```

with Modifiers for both param1 and paramN: `Text=!groups`

replace with:

```
@$Annotation$(timeOut = 100L, $param1$ = $value1$,/*...*/ $paramN$ = $valueN$)
```

Which almost works!

The problem I can't solve is that it also matches things like:

```
@Test(description = "should not match this test, but it does", groups = "SlowIntegrationTest")
```

That is, Annotations with parameters other than group. The ones that have *only* group are not matched.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following Structural Search & Replace should work.

##### Search template:

```
@Test($groups$ = $v$)
```

Modifiers:
`$group$` - text=`groups`, count=`[0,0]`

##### Replace template:

```
@Test(timeOut=100L)
```

Or copy the following complete template and `Import Template from Clipboard`:

```
<replaceConfiguration name="Add time-out to @Test" text="@Test($groups$ = $v$)" recursive="false" type="JAVA" pattern_context="default" reformatAccordingToStyle="true" shortenFQN="true" replacement="@Test(timeOut=100L)" case_sensitive="true">
  <constraint name="__context__" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="groups" regexp="groups" minCount="0" maxCount="0" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="v" within="" contains="" />
</replaceConfiguration>
```